# Get all bindings to a DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am wondering if it is possible to get all bindings that have a given `DependencyProperty` set as their **source**?

I was looking at the `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` class via the [DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(DependencyProperty, Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms655936.aspx) method, unfortunately without success. It only allows to register a listener for change notification, but it has no way to inspect the registered listeners (being bindings in my case).

I also looked in the BindingOperation class, where all operations work only on binding **targets**, not sources.

It would even suffice if I could get my hands on the multicast delegate of the registered listeners and get the invocation list.

**Edit**

After using some reflector magic I decided to try hooking into the Add/Remove ValueChanged methods on the PropertyDescriptor by implementing the  ICustomTypeDescriptor and intercepting the GetProperties method. From there i could intercept the delegates that are registering for change notifications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would also be interested to know this! Probably microsoft never gave any such API because its a counter-dependency requirement. In WPF the GUI (the Target!) is the driver for dependency value changes so all dependency properties rise or attach with target gui hence the APIs are target driven than the sources (which could be many for that target!).